# Configure footnote citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

I am writing my thesis and am 
having trouble with  footnote citations with two lines.

The minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}   

\usepackage[hyperref=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            doi=true,
            backref=true,
            style=custom-numeric-comp,
            citereset=chapter,
            maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=100,
            backend=bibtex,
            block=none]{biblatex}

\newlength{\spc} % declare a variable to save spacing value
\newcommand{\sjcitep}[2][]{% new command with two arguments: optional (#1) and mandatory (#2)
        \settowidth{\spc}{#1}% set value of \spc variable to the width of #1 argument
        \addtolength{\spc}{-1.8\spc}% subtract from \spc about two (1.8) of its values making its magnitude negative
        #1% print the optional argument
        \hspace*{\spc}% print an additional negative spacing stored in \spc after #1
        \supershortnotecite{#2}}% print (cite) the mandatory argument

\addbibresource{testbib}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}  

Citation here \sjcitep{MPT3}

\end{document}
```

The testbib.bib file is:

```
    @inproceedings{MPT3,
    author          =   {M. Herceg and M. Kvasnica and C.N. Jones and M. Morari},
    title           =   {{Multi-Parametric Toolbox 3.0}},
    booktitle       =   {Proceedings of the European Control Conference},
    year            =   {2013},
    address         =   {Z\"urich, Switzerland}
}
```

It also requires some files which can be downloaded at http://www.khirevich.com/downloads/example_latex_bib_foot.rar

The output citation looks like this:
[image]

Yet I would like this, i.e. two-lines citation should be aligned.
[image]

Comment: Your example code is not exactly minimal. Please edit it so that it's (a lot more) minimal and focused solely on the issue you're looking to fix.

Comment: Sorry, I have editted.

Comment: Sorry for this, it requires some additional files:
http://www.khirevich.com/downloads/example_latex_bib_foot.rar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily accomplished with the command `\deffootnote` (originally provided for KOMA classes, but can be used in typical classes like `book` by loading the `scrextend` package).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{testbib.bib}
    @inproceedings{MPT3,
        author          =   {M. Herceg and M. Kvasnica and C.N. Jones and M. Morari},
        title           =   {{Multi-Parametric Toolbox 3.0}},
        booktitle       =   {Proceedings of the European Control Conference},
        year            =   {2013},
        address         =   {Z\"urich, Switzerland}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}   
\usepackage{scrextend}  
\usepackage[hyperref=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            doi=true,
            backref=true,
            style=custom-numeric-comp,
            citereset=chapter,
            maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=100,
            backend=bibtex,
            block=none]{biblatex}

\newlength{\spc} % declare a variable to save spacing value
\newcommand{\sjcitep}[2][]{% new command with two arguments: optional (#1) and mandatory (#2)
        \settowidth{\spc}{#1}% set value of \spc variable to the width of #1 argument
        \addtolength{\spc}{-1.8\spc}% subtract from \spc about two (1.8) of its values making its magnitude negative
        #1% print the optional argument
        \hspace*{\spc}% print an additional negative spacing stored in \spc after #1
        \supershortnotecite{#2}}% print (cite) the mandatory argument


\deffootnote[2em]{2em}{1em}{%           <------------------
    \textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}

\addbibresource{testbib}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}  

Citation here \sjcitep{MPT3}

\end{document}
```

[image]